# inserting a function into a variable

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I'm learning Zend Framework 2 and in their Zend\Db documentation at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html they have the following code:

```
$qi = function($name) use ($adapter) { return $adapter->platform->quoteIdentifier($name);};
$fp = function($name) use ($adapter) { return $adapter->driver->formatParameterName($name); };
```

i've never seen this code of way to create functions.

the problem is that when I add this code to my class, eclipse complains with

```
  sytax error: unexpected "function"
```

and when I run this on my website, PHP complains

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)
```

using php 5.4

so.. do they have a bug in their documentation ? or am i missing something here ?

thanks

## update

my eclipse project is set up to version 5.4

my web interface php version is 5.5.1, so why do i still get these errors?

Comment: They're [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (also known as **closures**) - they shouldn't throw any errors with PHP 5.4...

Comment: Well Eclipse may complain, what about your actual Webserver? The Syntax is 100% valid

Comment: Maybe you have errors in *your* code? The code from the manual is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, those are [*anonymous functions*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and that code is perfectly valid. Anonymous functions exist in PHP since 5.3. If you're receiving syntax errors, you're *not* running PHP 5.3 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
<?
$adapter = 'y';
$qi = function($name) use ($adapter) { return $adapter->platform->quoteIdentifier($name);};
$fp = function($name) use ($adapter) { return $adapter->driver->formatParameterName($name); };
?>
```

PHP 5.4.9

Older (<5.4) versions of php didn't support this kind of anonymous functions.

Comment: i checked phpinfo() and i'm using version 5.5.1

Comment: Maybe the eclipse internal php parser recognises only <=5.3 PHP sytax

Answer (score 0):

Is the error on line 1? Are you uploading with FTP?

If that's the case your FTP is compressing everything into one line.

Try changing the transfer type in your FTP client from auto to binary, and re-upload.